# Windows could not detect this network's proxy settings - Brand new PC build

Tags: networking, windows-10, proxy, ethernet

Purchased a new PC here very decent system.

Even with the pre-installed windows 10 home I was having connectivity issues. The desktop it replaced was functioning fine connection wise and the other devices in the house are also fine (Mac, iPhones e.t.c).

The ethernet and wireless connection both show up in diagnoses as `windows could not detect this network's proxy settings`.
I tried everything, netsh commands, renewing IP, deleting drivers installing new ones all sorts. Even went as far as saying bugger it and installing a fresh Windows 10 which sorted the problem for a very short while but a restart soon messed it up again.

I'm am starting to think this is a problem with the board?

I am looking for any help or suggestions? Other devices are fine and the new build worked with a fresh Windows install very briefly (enough for me to install windows updates and driver software and such) but then borked again.

Starting to get really frustrated. I don't want to have to send it back but I am pretty sure I have exhausted all solutions.

[Full thread on PC Specialist Forum](https://www.pcspecialist.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?55537-windows-could-not-detect-this-network-s-proxy-settings)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the BT Home Hub. I think it didn't go through the parental controls the first time round so no DHCP was available until I restarted the router and followed the parental control screen.